# How to pass an object from React (GatsbyJS) to PyScript

Tags: python, reactjs, gatsby, pyscript, pyodide

I've created a form in GatsbyJS, and I'd like the data from that form to be passed into an external PyScript file, where it processes the data and returns a value.

I've found tutorials that suggest importing the object in the python file, like `from js import xyz`. I'm not sure if this would work in the case of React/GatsbyJS.

If this is even possible, kindly suggest how this can be implemented.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/73458196/2438933